# How to access item object outside "return" in react?

Tags: reactjs

I need some help...

I'm trying to access my object in a function to delete the object in my backend:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


function AllMeetupsPage() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [loadedMeets, setloadedMeets] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/').then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            setIsLoading(false)
            setloadedMeets(data)
        })
    }, [])

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <p>Loading...</p>
        )
    }

    if (loadedMeets.length === 0) {
        return (
            <p className="container"> NO DATA...</p>
        )
    }

    return (
        <section className="container">
            <div>
                {loadedMeets.map((item) => {
                    return <div teste='ASDAUSD' key={item._id} className='meetUpCard'>
                        <img className="meetUpImg" src={item.imageUrl} alt="" />
                        <div className="meetupDetails">
                            <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                            <small>{item._id}</small>
                            <p><i className="fas fa-info-circle"></i> {item.description}</p>
                            <div className='meetupActions'>
                                <button className='btn btn-details'>Details</button>
  <button className='btn btn-delete' onClick={handleDelete}><i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                })}
            </div>
        </section>

    )
}

export default AllMeetupsPage
```

My delete func:

```
    function handleDelete(item) {
        fetch('http://localhost:4000', {
            method: 'DELETE',
            body: JSON.stringify(item)
        })
    }
```

The problem is that I cant access the item object to send to my backend and delete it... How can I access this object? I mean, the button is part of the object it self, I don't understand why I cant pass to my function...

Thank you very much

Comment: In your `button` have you tried to actually pass the item to your `handleDelete` function ? Like so, `onClick={() => handleDelete(item)}` ?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `item` to your `handle` function, in order to know which `item` you want to `delete`.

```
<button className='btn btn-delete' onClick={() => handleDelete(item)}>
```